# 'AddDbContext' was called with configuration, but the context type only declares a parameterless constructor

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, dbcontext

I got an error while developing the project.

My codes are below..

Error Message :

> System.ArgumentException: ''AddDbContext' was called with
> configuration, but the context type 'NoteDbContext' only declares a
> parameterless constructor. This means that the configuration passed to
> 'AddDbContext' will never be used. If configuration is passed to
> 'AddDbContext', then 'NoteDbContext' should declare a constructor that
> accepts a DbContextOptions and must pass it to the base
> constructor for DbContext.'

DbContext

```
public class NoteDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
            "Server=DESKTOP-BELVBNK\\SQLEXPRESS;" +
            "DataBase=NoteAppDB;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    }

    public DbSet<Entities.Note> Notes { get; set; }
}
```

ASP.Net Project - Startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddDbContext<NoteDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("NoteAppDB")));
}
```

I searched for the solution of these errors, but could not find it.

Comment: "I get an error" so what is the error?!

Comment: I'm sorry but it's in the title.

Comment: No, that's a paraphrasing of the error. [edit] your question and include the entire error message or we cannot help.

Comment: Also,  are you using .NET 5 or 6? Are you using dependency injection? If so, why are you new-ing up all those object all the times?

Comment: using .Net 5 and I using dependeny injection

Comment: If you are using DI, then use it, don't `new` up objects manually as that breaks the entire point of DI.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? I'm still very new.

Comment: Honestly, I think you should go and run through some basic tutorials, you will learn far more and far quicker than asking individual questions on here.

Comment: The `NoteDbContext` class must expose a public constructor with a `DbContextOptions<NoteDbContext>` parameter. This is how context configuration from AddDbContext is passed to the DbContext.

Answer (score 5):

When you register a `DbContext` with `AddDbContext` you need to have a special constructor, like:

```
public NoteDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) {}
```

This is required. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/.